# Html5 Audio - currentTime reseting causes bitty sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

[Question edited to clarify points by users. My comments below have been deleted and included here instead.]

I have a long sound file (mp3), 110 seconds. At the start of this file the music is happy, but it gets progressively more sinister by the end. **Note: The audio will play at the normal speed throughout.**

I have a variable 'var tension;' which has a value between 0 and 1, eg 0.35. It measures how spooky things are getting in the game. A value of tension = 0.0 means its safe, a value of tension = 0.5 means there is a bit of trouble brewing, and a value of tension = 1.0 means the poop is hitting the fan. But all decimal values between 0.0 and 1.0 can be achieved. It is set by how close you are to danger or if someone is chasing you.

The following is a global Audio element created in memory at the start of the program:

```
var g_TensionSound = new Audio();
g_TensionSound.src = "mysoundfile.mp3";
```

I have waited for the mp3 file to be fully loaded.

Every second I use a timer event to call the following bit of code:

```
g_TensionSound.currentTime = 5.0 + 100 * tension;
if(g_TensionSound.paused) g_TensionSound.play();
```

So for example the first time the timer event is triggered tension = 0;, so it plays a friendly sound in the music file (ie at the 5 second mark). Then the next time the timer event is triggered, the player has moved close to some trouble and tension has risen to tension = 0.25; So this time the segment of music at the 30 second (5 + tension * 100) mark in the file will be played.

Unfortunately this produces very bitty results, with a slight delay when changing over to the new currentTime. **Does anyone know anything about this, or how to solve it?**

Comment: May I ask what the point of this is?

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure what tension is, and why you'd need to apply it to playing the audio. Does tension refer to the speed of the audio being played? Would you be able to provide more code and/or an example (like with jsFiddle)?

Comment: Ahh okay, I thought "tension" was some official Audio term. But once you mentioned the spookyness of the game, that makes more sense. I'll see if I can figure anything out

Comment: I guess I'm confused again. So you're not trying to change the speed of the Audio playing, right? You seem to be trying to target a specific time in the audio. If you're running `g_TensionSound.currentTime = 5.0 + 100 * tension;` every second, and `tension` isn't changing, then the audio just gets reset to the result of `5.0 + 100 * tension`